# Made a typo doing an apt-get in Ubuntu, fixed typo, error continued as if typo never changed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Simply put, i'm provisioning my VM with Docker, so I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://downlolad.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

I ran, got an error that could not resolve 'downlolad.docker.com;.
Simple typo, easy fix.
Basically I run it again, download.docker.com this time, no typo, but the same error keeps popping up? Even when I do a sudo apt-get update, the typo error pops up, so I cant download anything at all. What do I do?

Comment: `no typo, but the same error keeps popping up` – So the new error says `downlolad` as if the typo was there? or `download`?

Comment: it says "downlolad" as if the typo is still there

Comment: Apparently you didn't remove the wrong repo, just added the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The reference to `downlolad.docker.com` is still in your repository list.

Remove the entry from the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and run `sudo apt-get update` and try the `add-apt-repository` command again.

Comment: Actually, my /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty?

Comment: Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list` _file_, not the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` _directory_.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the repository, with the typo, to the apt sources. Find it and delete it from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

For an easy one liner to quickly delete it, you can run:

```
sudo sed -e '/downlolad\.docker\.com/d' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, instead of editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` or similar file by hand (as other answers suggest), you can remove the erroneous entry by invoking `add-apt-repository` with the `--remove` option and the same string:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb [arch=amd64] https://downlolad.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

My tests indicate that if you tried to add the troublesome repository more than once (you probably didn't, it's a general remark), you may have more than one erroneous `# deb-src` line in the file. In such case you may need to invoke the command (with `--remove`) more than once. If you don't, any leftover `# deb-src` line is commented out anyway, so it shouldn't matter; yet it's garbage.

So after all I would check the file(s) just in case. This answer is to acknowledge the existence of `--remove` option.

Comment: This was it! Thank you, invoking --remove was what I needed, my /etc/appt/sources.list.d was empty.